# update the textfield as we change the value in datetime picker

Tags: iphone

I am making an iPhone app in which I am using date time picker and displaying the selected the date in a text filed. Now I want to update the textfield as there is change in selected date in date picker.

hOw can i do this. Give me some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to check the nsdateformatter and the method called stringFromDate:

Comment: refer http://mattjdrake.tumblr.com/post/213894058/how-to-use-uidatepicker-from-uikit-in-iphone

Comment: Actually I want to update the textfield, whenever I change the date in date time picker. For displaying the date I am using nsdateformatter and stringfromdate. Now I want to change the date in textfield as I touch the date time picker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can be notified of `UIDatePicker` changes by simply adding a target & action for the control event `UIControlEventValueChanged`. Check the [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) reference for more details.

A simple implementation would look something like this:

```
 [picker addTarget:self 
            action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and then...

```
   - (void)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender{
        UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker *)sender;
        NSString *dateString;

        dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[picker date]
                                                    dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle 
                                                    timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

        [textField setText:dateString];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

connect this action to `datepicker valuechange` method so when you change date it will show in `textField`.

```
-(IBAction)pkrValueChange:(UIDatePicker*)sender{

    textField.text = [[sender date] description];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2 Xcode 10.1**

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)

@objc
private func datePickerValueChanged() {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    yourTextField.text = "\(dateString)"
}
```